# Ruby on Rails Why isn't my create user working using bcyrpt gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, registration

In my Ruby on Rails application I have just started to try to include registering and logging in. I firstly ran the  scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string password_digest:string role:string
```

and then `rake db:migrate`. This all went well and created the needed files for User. In my gemfile I installed the `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'` gem, and then added the following into user.rb model.

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    has_secure_password
end
```

And edited my /views/users/_form.html.erb to look like the following:

```
 <div class="form1">

  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name, 'Name:' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password, 'Password:' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password , size: 40 %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm:' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>

 <% end %>

</div>
```

My create method in the users_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  # login is achieved by saving a user's 'id' in a session variable, 
  # accessible to all pages
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "#{@user.name} - you have successfully registered."
else
  render action: "new"
end
```

end

But for some reason on my form when I add a new user it isn't saving the details, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is there any error displayed in the console? Do check that.
2. Are you defining user_params?

Comment: There's no error, and I don't know if I'm defining user_params

Comment: You have to define something like this in your users controller:

    `private
        def user_params
              params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password,:password_confirmation)
        end`

These are called strong parameters. You need to tell rails which parameters are allowed to be written by the user. Read this: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Thank you!! I had this in there before: `def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password_digest, :role)
    end` so was missing the `:password_confirmation`

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: We reached the answer part in the comments. Please check @RailsOuter